# XPathSelectElement on results from XPathSelectElements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

OK, having some issues where I can run XPathSelectElements to get the three (in this specific case, although it could be X number) set of nodes that i want to pull information from. I'm scraping some HTML that is XHTML compliant and having to use XPathSelectElements to find the X number of, in this example, Order object.

Consider HTML/XML simplied to something like this:

```
<RandomInfo>
<NAME>ASDSADS</NAME>
<WHAT>Dunno</NAME>
<div id='OrderResults'>
  <div id='order_foo'>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Customer>Bill</Customer>
    <Total>500</Total>
  </div>
  <div id='order_bar'>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Customer>Bob</Customer>
    <Total>200</Total>
  </div>
  <div id='order_abc'>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Customer>Butch</Customer>
    <Total>100</Total>
  </div>
</div>
</RandomInfo>
```

the "order_*" names are dynamic and cannot be relied on for selecting nodes. So I have an XPathSelectElements that correctly gets the set of the three divs for me. But, then when I iterate thorugh each XNode returned and try to call XPathSelectElement("//Customer") I always get the same value back for that XPathSelectElement call. I can use VS to see that the node object is changing, but the XPathSelectElement is not getting from the current node. How do I force it to 'root' at itself instead if apparently somehow going back in to the parent node/doc to get the value?

Comment: Welcome to [so], can you post a small snippet of the C# code? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this xpath

`./Customer`

`.` represents the current node(usually implied)

`/` represents childern of that particular node

Answer (score 1):

And // at the start of an XPath represents any node from the root of the document. So you may be be in any node, it will always match all Customer node of your document. // (wether at beginning of xpath or in the middle) is very bad for performance and should be avoided !